# [Tailwind CSS]Empty div don't show in browser

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS with Next.js, and want to show progress bar in below url.

https://www.tailwind-kit.com/components/progress

The code is below:

```
<div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg w-72 shadow block p-4 m-auto">
        <div class="w-full h-2 bg-gray-400 rounded-full mt-3">
            <div class="w-3/4 h-full text-center text-xs text-white bg-green-500 rounded-full">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, If I check browser, the bar is not displayed and the height of the div element is 0.
I checked in Chrome and Safari, and the result was the same in both.

I want to know how to show the empty div element in browser.

--Update:

I have solved the above problem by removing the height customize from tailwind.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    // removed this
    height: {
      main: '681px'
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

However, I don't know why the height customize caused this problem, does anyone know about it?

Comment: well your code should work. https://play.tailwindcss.com/EOwkrh3djk can you reproduce your problem ?

Comment: Seems like if we can have a over view of the over all parent element it will be helpful, as the code snippet you posted works fine on Tailwind Play

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem.
I have added the height customize in tailwind.config.js, and when I removed it, it works.
However, I don't know why this setting caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could use grow Property:

```
<div class="grow w-3/4 h-full ....">
```